# APT: Pinning package origin & apt proxy on packages resources list

Tags: proxy, debian, apt

I try to configure priority pinning with APT on Debian 8, to force a package installation from a specific repository.

My servers are configured to use an apt proxy, specified on each lines of /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://<my-apt-cacher-ng-proxy>:9999/ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
deb http://<my-apt-cacher-ng-proxy>:9999/ftp.igh.cnrs.fr/pub/mariadb/repo/10.0/debian sid main
```

I would like to use 'MariaDB' repository for a specific package 'libmysqlclient18'.

The recommended way is to add an apt preference, indicating that origin "ftp.igh.cnrs.fr" weight more than default repos, for example like this:

```
/etc/apt/preferences.d/libmysqlclient18.conf
Package: libmysqlclient18
Pin: origin ftp.igh.cnrs.fr
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

But as I use a proxy, every origins in my conf refers to <my-apt-cacher-ng-proxy>...

Is there a way to force the repos .?
I tried some alternatives with no success:

```
Pin: release o=MariaDB
Pin: release l=MariaDB
...
```

I even tried to indicate that Debian base package should not be installed, with no success either:

```
Package: libmysqlclient18
Pin: release n=Jessie
# OR: Pin: release o=Debian
Pin-Priority: -10
```

Same result every time: the two repos. keep the same 500 priority

```
$ aptitude versions libmysqlclient18
Paquet libmysqlclient18 :
p   5.5.42-1                          testing       500
p   10.0.17+maria-1~sid               <NULL>        500
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, by asking apt to consider everything comming from MariaDB as more important... this is ok as this repository only contains 4 or 5 packages, but is not the ideal solution!

```
Package: *
Pin: release o=MariaDB
Pin-Priority: 999
```

If I only indicate one package instead of '`*`', it stops working. Even '`Package: libmysql*`' does not work.